# Express Server, MySQL query breaks when using parameters as input for query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Express Server running on Ubuntu VM. It connects to a MySQL database and calls a procedure that returns some data. And it all works perfectly fine until this part:

```
var mysqlquery = 'CALL p_CategoriesSumRes(' + parseInt(req.params.resolution) + ', "2020-08-02 00:00:00")';
var mysqlquery = 'CALL p_CategoriesSumRes(' + 2 + ', "2020-08-02 00:00:00")';
```

Between these two lines, the second one works perfectly fine, but the first one gives me this error:

```
Example app listening at http://localhost:8000
/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'field list'
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/tealeech/backend/app.js:34:9)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Handshake._callback (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Handshake.Sequence.OkPacket (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:92:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/home/rootuser/Desktop/HTML/project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
```

I tested it and mysqlquery from the first line is the exact same as the second one(when connecting to http://192.168.178.85:8000/2).
I don't run both lines at once, obviously.

What is this cursed magic?

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();




const port = 8000;

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://192.168.178.85:3000',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}


app.get('/:resolution', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res) {

  res.setHeader('response-type', 'text/plain');
  const mysql = require('mysql');
    
  
  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "IP ADDRESS",
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    database: "DB"
  });
  
  con.connect(function(err) {
    var mysqlquery = 'CALL p_CategoriesSumRes(' + parseInt(req.params.resolution) + ', "2020-08-02 00:00:00")'; //<========== DOESN'T WORK
    var mysqlquery = 'CALL p_CategoriesSumRes(' + 2 + ', "2020-08-02 00:00:00")'; //<========== WORKS

    if (err) throw err;
    con.query(mysqlquery, function (err, result, fields) {

      if (err) throw err;
      var row = result[0];


      res.send(JSON.stringify(row));
      

    });
    
  });
  
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: pleasse check which parameters req has, because req.params.resolution doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using wrong quotes.

try

```
var mysqlquery = 'CALL p_CategoriesSumRes(' + parseInt(req.params.resolution) + ", '2020-08-02 00:00:00')";
var mysqlquery = 'CALL p_CategoriesSumRes(' + 2 + ", '2020-08-02 00:00:00')";
```